# Remove line from first and last child

Tags: css

I've got this timeline code, I am trying to remove the line on top of first child and from last child, how can I get this border, do I need to add another absolute element to cover it up or?
[Image what I want removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ9QT.png)
Same goes for the line after End button.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.tree {
  position: relative;
}

.tree {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  border-left: 1px solid #abaaed;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

li::before {
    content: '';
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #4e5ed3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8px;
}

li::after {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    top: auto;
    background: #4e5ed3;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul class="tree">
<li><Button>Start</Button></li>

<li>
Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
</li>
<li><Button>
End</Button></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: for first child:  `nth-child(1)` for Last `:nth-last-child(1)`

Comment: Yeah but I can't just remove the bit of border, it removes entire border from left

Comment: Exactly, You can't do that, You have to rethink your approach to achieving this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using background instead of border.

```css
:root {
  --circle-size: 15px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.tree {
  position: relative;
}

.tree {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  --line-padding: 0px;
  --y-position: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#abaaed, #abaaed) 0 var(--y-position) / 1px calc(100% - var(--line-padding)) no-repeat;
}

li:first-child,
li:last-child {
  --line-padding: 15px;
}

li:first-child {
  --y-position: 100%;
}

li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #4e5ed3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
}

li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: auto;
  background: #4e5ed3;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="tree">
    <li>
      <Button>Start</Button>
    </li>

    <li>
      Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
    </li>
    <li>
      <Button>
End</Button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```